# Autokeras - Get classes name

Tags: python, keras, automl, auto-keras

I am trying to get the classes names I used for Autokeras.
Both sentences and labels are strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import autokeras as ak


df = pd.read_csv("train.csv", names=['text', 'category'])
sentences = df.text.values
labels = df.category.values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sentences, labels, test_size=0.10, random_state=2021)

clf = ak.TextClassifier(overwrite=True, max_trials=2)  
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=400)
predicted_y = clf.predict(x_test)
clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Now when I try importing to keras and running the prediction on a sample I'm only getting an index number.

```
model = clf.export_model()
probas = model.predict(["Hello world"])
predicted_class = probas.argmax(axis=-1)
```

predicted_class returns:

> [20]

This assumes I have a list of the classes that were used with their order or a dict.

How can I know which string was assigned the index 20?

Comment: Try name_of_predicted_class=labels[predicted_class] and check does it work.

Comment: @Experience_In_AI no its a list with the same categories.

Comment: This is a quess only ... does this work: labels_unique_only=list(dict.fromkeys(labels)) and after that name_or_predicted_class=labels_unique_only[predicted_class]

Comment: @Experience_In_AI doing a set and then sorting it worked :)